# How to add and extract bits to a byte?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I am trying to understand `bit` and `byte manipulation` and I have seen many examples in `SO`. Still, I have some questions regarding my understanding.

First, lets say we have a `byte array` with the byte order as `Least Significant Byte`. I want to get the byte 2 from this array. I can get the byte like `byte[1]`. Am I right?

Second, we have a `byte array` with the byte order as `Least Significant Byte`. And I want to get first 2 bits of the byte 1!. How can I get the first 2 bits from that byte? 
Also, how can I add a number into the first 2 bits of a byte?

Any help or link to understand those logics are much appreciated.

Comment: You can bitwise operators like shits (`<<` and  `>>`) and `$`. Or  you can use *bitfields*.

Comment: "I can get the byte and use it without any modification right?" this question is unclear to me. What you mean by "get it and use it without any modification"?

Comment: Huh, if you have a byte array and you want byte 2 out of it it's either `array[1]` or `array[2]` depending on what you mean by 2 (second or index 2). LSB, MSB is irrelevant because you have a byte array and you want a byte. Please read your question again and check you've used the correct word (bit/ byte) in all places. I think you've mixed them up

Comment: @CaiusJard Your explanation cleared a part of my confusion, thank you. I think I have written my question correctly. Which part you mean?

Comment: @Dennis.M the first question is still very unclear and confusing...

Comment: Note that LSB means least significant _bit_, not byte. Byte order (endianess) only matters in case you try to serialize integers or floats. Otherwise index 0 of a byte array is always the least significant. To mask out bits from a byte, simply use the bitwise operators as advised by your C book.

Comment: More info: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: @Lundin Actually, LSB is ambiguous, can stand for [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_byte)...

Comment: @Aconcagua No, the de facto industry standard meaning is bit. The wikipedia source used in that link is some hobbyist's trash site.

Comment: @Lundin Get 2 bits from a byte is `first_2bits = (num >> 6) & 0xFF;`. Am I right?

Comment: @Dennis.M considering `num` is a 8 bit value and you mean by first 2 bits the most significant bits, yes.

Comment: @Dennis.M That code gives you the 2 most significant bits, bit number 6 and 7.

Comment: @Lundin Any reference for? Have seen counter examples, although not having one by hand at the moment...

Comment: @Dennis.M `(num >> 6) & 0xff` might give you unexpected results, if `char` is signed on your system and most significant bit is set; `num` will be promoted to `int`, but sign extension occurs, and if right shift is arithmitic shift (usually for signed values), you'll end up in having ones at bit locations 2, 3, ... , 7. If you don't want these, you'd have `(num >> 6) & 0x03`.

Comment: @Lundin That will give the most significant bits, if the bit order is most significant bit. If the bit order is least significant bit, it will give the 2 least significant bits. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Dennis.M There only exists one bit order on all computers. Bit 7 is always the MSB.

Comment: @Lundin Then why there is `Most Significant Bits` and `Least Significant Bits`. I didn't get.

Comment: Because on a 16 bit word the MSB is number 15, on a 32 bit word MSB is number 31 and so on.

Comment: @Lundin Cleared!

Comment: @Dennis.M LSB/MSB can play an important role, though, if you have protocols based on serial transmission (i. e. only one bit at a time), such as SPI, I²C, 1-wire, ... If you only transmit one bit at a time, *then* you need to know if first bit transmitted is LSB or MSB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, lets say we have a byte array with the byte order as LSB. I want to get the byte 2 from this array. I can get the byte like byte[1]. Am I right?

Yes.

> Second, we have a byte array with the byte order as LSB. And I want to get first 2 bits of the byte 1!. How can I get the first 2 bits from that byte? Also, how can I add a number into the first 2 bits of a byte?

You can use the bitwise AND operator `&` with the constant `3` to retrieve only the first two bits. By doing `num & 3` it will realize a condition operation between each bit of `num` and `3` returning 1 as resultant bit only if both bits are 1. As `3` have only its 2 first bits set, every bit in `num` other than the first 2 will be ignored.

```
unsigned char foo = 47;
unsigned char twobits = foo & 3; // this will return only the value of the two bits of foo.
unsigned char number_to_add = 78;
twobits &= (number_to_add & 3); // this will get the values of the 2 bits of number_to_add_ and then assign it to the 2 bits of variable twobits.
```

Or if you don't care of the *endianess* you can use bitfields:

```
struct st_foo
{
     unsigned char bit1 : 1;
     unsigned char bit2 : 1;
     unsigned char the_rest : 6;
};

struct st_foo my_byte;
my_byte.bit1 = 1;
my_byte.bit2 = 0;
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that "bit1" in your bit-field example is the LSB. Furthermore, bits are always enumerated from 0 to 7, not from 1 to 8.

Comment: Also, `unsigned char` need not be a valid type to be used for bit-fields, it isn't guaranteed to work by the standard. Your example relies on compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think if I got it. C standard doesn't rules bit-fields? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @Lundin so if I understood well I could use `st_foo` to be treated as a 8 bit value but could not count on the bit ordering? That means any code that relies on bit-field structures are implementation-specific?

Comment: No, you can treat it as a chunk of binary, containing 3 other chunks of binary, in unspecified order. Yes, code that uses bit-fields is very implementation-specific and completely non-portable, while at the same time not offering any advantages.

Comment: @Lundin got it, thanks for the clarification, but don't you think a code that uses bit-fields are more readable than one relying on shifts and other bitwise operators (considering the bit ordering is not important)?

Comment: Bitwise operations are so incredibly common that they _should_ be readable to any C programmer. Long as the number of operations on a single line are kept low.